# Phalcon редактирование данных в БД

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

Нужно в настройках админки указывать название сайта и подвал.

В контроллере прописал:

```
$settings        = new Settings();
$settings->title = $title;
$settings->foot  = $foot;

if($settings->save()){
      $this->flash->success('<b>Сохранено</b><p>Основные настройки сохранены</p>');
}
```

но после этого у меня в БД создается новая запись, а не редактируется существующая.

Как сохранить данные в БД?

В https://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/models.html написано, что можно через `model->save();` сохранять.

Чем отличается метод `$settings->save()` от `$settings->create()`?

По сути, получается, ничем: в обоих случаях в БД заносится новая запись, хотя, по моей логике, `Save()` должен сохранять запись, а не создавать новую.

Comment: Все рабозрался :)

Вместо $settings        = new Settings();, нужно было использовать: $settings = Settings::findFirst(1);

Comment: Чтобы обновить объект, его сначала надо получить. Когда вы создаете его через new, для фреймворка это выглядит, как будто вы хотите создать новую запись.